# Moving back in Python filestream

Tags: python

I am trying to write a compiler and read in a file one character at a time. If I were to find "/" followed by another "/" then I want to interpret the rest of my line as a comment. I am using file.read(1) each time I want another character. However, if I see that I have "/" followed by something that is not a "/" is there any way I can move the file stream back one character so as to not lose that character?

```
def tokenType(self):
    # PAGE 108
    if (self.current == '{' or self.current == '}'  or self.current == '('  or self.current == ')'  or self.current == '['  or self.current == ']'  or self.current == '.'  or self.current == ','  or self.current == ';'  or self.current == '-'  or self.current == '*'  or self.current == '/'  or self.current == '&'  or self.current == '|'  or self.current == '<'  or self.current == '>'  or self.current == '='  or self.current == '~'):
        if (self.current == '/'):
            next = self.file.read(1)
            if (next == '/'):
                while (next != "\n"):
                    next = self.file.read(1)
                return "IGNORE"
            if (next == '*'):
                while (True):
                    next = self.file.read(1)
                    if (next == '*'):
                        next = self.file.read(1)
                        if (next == '/'):
                            break
                return "IGNORE"
            else:
                return "SYMBOL"
        return "SYMBOL"
    elif (self.current == " " or self.current == "\n"):
        return "IGNORE"
    elif (self.current == "'"):
        while(next != "'"):
            self.current = self.current + next
        return "STRING_CONST"
    elif (type(self.current) == int):
        next = self.file.read(1)
        while(next != " "):
            self.current = self.current + next
        return "INT_CONST"
    else:
        next = self.file.read(1)
        while(next != " " and next != ""):
            self.current = self.current + next
            next = self.file.read(1)
        if (self.current == 'class' or self.current == 'constructor'  or self.current == 'function'  or self.current == 'method'  or self.current == 'field'  or self.current == 'static'  or self.current == 'var'  or self.current == 'int'  or self.current == 'char'  or self.current == 'boolean'  or self.current == 'void'  or self.current == 'true'  or self.current == 'false'  or self.current == 'null'  or self.current == 'this'  or self.current == 'let'  or self.current == 'do'  or self.current == 'if' or self.current == 'else'  or self.current == 'while'  or self.current == 'return'):
            return "KEYWORD"
        else:
            return "IDENTIFIER"
```

My problem seems to be when I have something like 10/5 and my program checks to see if the next character is a "/". Then on the next pass through my character interpreting function, the 5 has already been removed when it was checking for a comment.

So, is there any way I can get a character from a file stream without it being "removed" from the stream or is there a way I can move it back a character when I hit a case like this?

Comment: Please show a relevant code fragment.

Comment: `self.file.seek(-1, 1)` for moving -1 from current position.

Comment: `file.seek` works, but I question your strategy of reading one character at a time.  You need to do more research on lexing in order to tokenize your input into more meaningful chunks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty, but you could pass the current and next symbol into your function if you don't mind reading the entire file into memory.  You would only need some way to track ignoring the next character.

```
data = open('input_file').read()

for first, second in zip(data, data[1:]):
    tokenType(first, second)
```

But like roippi says, there are better ways to lex input.